# L-System with Java

Tags: java

I try to draw a Sierpinski Triangle using L-System and Java.

But my code don't draw anything.

I think my problem is in main class, at line: `if(rs1.equals('A') || rs1.equals('B'))`

Main class:

```
 package rule;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.geom.*;

 public class Test extends JFrame{

 public Test(){
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setSize(450,450);

  }


public static void main(String[] args) {

// draw 
 Test s=new Test();
    s.setVisible(true);

}

 @Override
 @SuppressWarnings("IncompatibleEquals")
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);  
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

Rule r1=new Rule("A","+B-A-B+");
Rule r2=new Rule("B","-A+B+A-");
Rule r3=new Rule("+","+");
Rule r4=new Rule("-","-");

RuleSet rs1 = new RuleSet();
rs1.addRule(r1);
rs1.addRule(r2);
rs1.addRule(r3);
rs1.addRule(r4);

    Pointer p0=new Pointer(50,50,60);
    Pointer pt_temp=p0;
    int dim_segment = 100;

    if(rs1.equals('A') || rs1.equals('B'))
           {

            int x_tmp=(int)Math.round(pt_temp.getX()+dim_segment*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pt_temp.getU())));    
            int y_tmp=(int)Math.round(pt_temp.getY()-dim_segment*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pt_temp.getU())));    
            g2.drawLine(pt_temp.getX(),pt_temp.getY(),x_tmp,y_tmp);
            pt_temp.setX(x_tmp);
            pt_temp.setY(y_tmp);

            }
    else  if(rs1.equals('+'))
                {
                    pt_temp.setU((int)(+pt_temp.getU()));

                }    
    else if(rs1.equals('-'))
                {
                    pt_temp.setU((int)(-pt_temp.getU()));

                }

}

}
```

LSystem.java :

```
class LSystem {
private String axiom;
private RuleSet rules = new RuleSet();

LSystem(String axiom, RuleSet rules) {
this.axiom = axiom;
this.rules = rules;
}

String derive(int steps){
  String tmp=axiom;      
  for(int i=0; i < steps; i++) {
      String str="";
      for(int j=0;j<tmp.length();j++)
        {
        String s=""+tmp.charAt(j);
        Rule r=rules.getRule(s);
        str+=r.getRight();
        }
      tmp=str;
  }
     return tmp;
} 
}
```

RuleSet.java :

```
class RuleSet {
private ArrayList<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<Rule>();
void addRule(Rule r) {
this.rules.add(r);
}

Rule getRule(String left) {
    for(int i=0; i<rules.size();i++){
    Rule r = rules.get(i);
    if(r.getLeft().equals(left))
        return r;}
    return null;
}
}
```

Rule.java :

```
public class Rule {

private String left;
private String right;

Rule(String left, String right) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}

String getLeft() {
return this.left;
}

String getRight() {
return this.right;
}



 }
```

Pointer.java :

```
public class Pointer {
private  int X;
private  int Y;
private  int U; //unghi

Pointer(int X, int Y, int U) {
    this.X = X;
    this.Y = Y;
    this.U = U;
}

int getX() {
return this.X;
}

int getY() {
return this.Y;
}

int getU() {
return this.U;
}

int setX(int X) {
  return this.X;  
}

int setY(int Y) {
  return this.Y;  
}

int setU(int U) {
  return this.U;  
}
}
```

So, please help me....

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Why do you suppress the warning instead of following its advice? You are comparing incompatible types.

Comment: Yes, rs1 is String and 'A' is char. But how do I make conversion ?

Comment: `rs1` is not a string. Its type is `RuleSet`. It can't be equal to neither a `char` nor a `String`. It doesn't even have its own `equals` method. Perhaps you want to create a method, named 'matchesChar' or something in `RuleSet` that compares a given `char` to something inside the `RuleSet` and returns a boolean that says if it matches or not?